# SSIS parent doesn't need password but child packages do - how do I get this to run in SQL server Agent?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-agent

I have a parent package that simply calls 4 child packages. All of these (parent and child) packages have been saved with package passwords. However only 2 of these child packages have non-sql connections and hence you're only asked to put in these passwords when opening them in the IDE. I don't know why you're not asked for the parent one but that's another issue.

However in SQL Server Agent (that runs this parent package) you're not asked to enter the package password (even though the package password is set in the parent package) because (I'm assuming for the same reason the IDE doesn't ask)

So when the parent goes to call the child packages that do ask, they fail. They're all stored in SQL Integration Services as Stored Packages and the password was entered when they were imported.

How do I get the child packages to work? I've tried putting it on the Agent command line that runs the parent package as "/DE password" but that doesn't seem to be passed to the child package.

I've also tried adding it to the SSISConfig db as a parent package variable but that also doesn't seem to work?

How do I get this to work?

Comment: The error I get is The protection level of the package requires a password, but PackagePassword property is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the package password in from the parent via a parent package variable. Just add the variable value to the "Set Values" tab of the sql agent job.

What is the protection level of the child package?